# Nodemailer not sending email in lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, nodemailer

I am developing an AWS lambda function using node.js 14.x for my runtime.

I create a nodemailer layer and upload it to my lambda function.  I am trying to test my function and just return a simple console log but I don't see the console log anywhere including my cloud watch logs.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
  const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      //   user: process.env.USER_NAME,
      //   pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
      user: "********",
      pass: "********",
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "taxs@gmail.com",
    to: "trdmon@gmail.com",
    subject: "subject",
    text: "message",
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    console.log('hit')
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      }
    });
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

If the `transporter.sendEmail` function were running I should see the console log.  Any ideas why my function isn't running?